# Bootstrap align list item

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a list with checkbox

[image]

How do I make Sheet3 and Science just align vertically left. Currently the science goes below the checkbox

```html
<div class="dropdown selection-l9zgqjql-gz80fbqg w-book-select w-50">
<input type="text" class="form-control form-select dropdown-toggle show" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" value="All Sheets" aria-expanded="true" data-bs-auto-close="outside" readonly="" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;">
<div class="dropdown-menu p-0 w-100 show" data-popper-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px);">
    <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item" style="
">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3 this is a bigger title of the science" checked=""> Sheet3 this is a bigger title of the science </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by; "just align vertically left"?

Comment: try `.list-group label{  display: flex;flex-direction: row;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed width of `dropdown-menu` and `dropdown`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="dropdown selection-l9zgqjql-gz80fbqg w-book-select" style="width: fit-content;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-select dropdown-toggle show" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" value="All Sheets" aria-expanded="true" data-bs-auto-close="outside" readonly="" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;">
  <div class="dropdown-menu p-0 show" data-popper-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); min-width: max-content;">
    <div class="list-group">
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item" style="
">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3 this is a bigger title of the science" checked=""> Sheet3 this is a bigger title of the science </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet1" checked=""> Sheet1 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet2" checked=""> Sheet2 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet3" checked=""> Sheet3 </label>
      <label class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" name="workbookSelection" value="Sheet4" checked=""> Sheet4 </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

```
.list-group-item {
 display: flex;
 align-items: start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make somthing like this in css:

```
label{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

and to be sure put the text into a span